# A crossword with a single clue

Tags: cipher, cryptic-clues, crosswords

Each number corresponds to a distinct letter. There are some non-words, such as names of things: people, gods, places, etc. Can you reconstruct the crossword?

[image: crossword]

**In green (1 to 5): Amusing key glues crazy. (5)**

Here is a text version of the table, if anyone needs it:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 10 | 3 | 11 | 12 | 9 | 13 | 14 | 11 | 13 | ■ | 15 |
| 13 | 9 | ■ | 16 | 11 | 11 | ■ | 11 | 13 | 9 | 6 | 7 |
| 6 | 2 | 13 | 20 | 3 | 10 | ■ | 16 | ■ | 17 | 9 | 18 |
| ■ | 6 | ■ | ■ | 12 | 20 | ■ | 16 | 16 | 9 | 17 | 9 |
| 19 | 20 | 18 | 4 | 11 | 3 | 12 | ■ | 9 | ■ | ■ | 16 |
| ■ | 11 | 16 | ■ | ■ | 9 | 11 | ■ | 1 | 16 | 20 | 21 |
| 10 | 13 | 20 | 11 | 1 | ■ | 7 | 6 | 7 | ■ | 3 | 7 |
| 7 | ■ | 1 | 20 | 13 | 9 | ■ | 13 | 2 | 17 | ■ | 21 |
| 22 | 11 | 1 | 1 | 11 | 13 | 12 | 7 | 3 | ■ | 6 | ■ |
| 20 | 19 | ■ | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 3 |
| ■ | ■ | 17 | 11 | 19 | 20 | 9 | ■ | 9 | 13 | 9 | 11 |
| 14 | 9 | 11 | 16 | ■ | 18 | ■ | 10 | 20 | 3 | 20 | 13 |
| 9 | 10 | 9 | 6 | 23 | 9 | ■ | ■ | 3 | 9 | 3 | 7 |
| 14 | ■ | 19 | 7 | 11 | ■ | 12 | 6 | 11 | 17 | ■ | ■ |
| 14 | 13 | 7 | 8 | 3 | ■ | 9 | 13 | ■ | 11 | 15 | 11 |
| ■ | 7 | 8 | 11 | 3 | ■ | 17 | 9 | 3 | 3 | 11 | 13 |
| 11 | 3 | ■ | 13 | 5 | 11 | ■ | 21 | 9 | 6 | 11 | 13 |

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, I see the word "16 16 9 17 9" near the top right. Words starting with double letters are rare, and the only English word which fits this is LLAMA. That gives us:

- 9 = A
- 16 = L
- 17 = M

Then in the upper middle we have a 3-letter word "16 11 11", which must be either LEE or LOO. There are no 6-letter words beginning with AO and ending with A, so it must be LEE, giving:

- 11 = E

Now we have "13 9 7 9" near the top right and "9 13 9 11" on the right-hand side, leading me to the conclusion that these are [RAMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rama) and [ARAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arae). So:

- 13 = R

The word "A R 6" in the top left must be ART or ARC or ARK (since E and M are taken). The relative frequency of 6, as well as the words "12 6 E M" and "6 R A 21" in the lower right and "E R A 6 7" in the upper right, suggests that:

- 6 = T

Then "E R A 6 7" must be [ERATO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erato) (and "7 6 7" in the middle is [OTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordo_Templi_Orientis)), giving:

- 7 = O

And "12 T E M" in the lower right must be STEM, giving:

- 12 = S

The combination of "S E 3 S E" at the top and "M A 3 3 E R" at the bottom right makes me quite sure that:

- 3 = N

Now the combination of "23 E N N 5" at the bottom and "T R O 5" in the middle makes me quite sure that:

- 5 = Y

The words "R 2 M" in the middle and "10 20 N 20 R "on the right tell me that 2 and 20 are both vowels, so they must be I and U in some order. The word "T 8 A 20 N" on the right, as well as the relative frequencies of 2 and 20, gives:

- 2 = U
- 20 = I

At this stage I finally solved the cryptic clue:

> Amusing key glues crazy = FUNKY (FUN+KY ~ crazy), so

- 1 = F
- 4 = K

Mopping up several in quick succession: "22 E F F E R S O N" is obviously JEFFERSON, "F R E U 19" is obviously FREUD, "E I F F E L T O 8 E R" is obviously EIFFEL TOWER; "10 R I E F" could be either BRIEF or GRIEF, but "T U R I N 10" makes clear which one. So:

- 8 = W
- 10 = G
- 19 = D
- 22 = J

Now "A G N E S A R 14 E R" must be [AGNES ARBER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agnes_Arber) and "D I 18 K E N S" must be DICKENS and "F L I 21" must be FLIP and "A G A T 23 A" must be AGATHA, so:

- 14 = B
- 18 = C
- 21 = P
- 23 = H

Finally, "15 O C A L P O P" must be VOCAL POP, so:

- 15 = V

And the final solution is:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | G | N | E | S | A | R | B | E | R | ■ | V |
| R | A | ■ | L | E | E | ■ | E | R | A | T | O |
| T | U | R | I | N | G | ■ | L | ■ | M | A | C |
| ■ | T | ■ | ■ | S | I | ■ | L | L | A | M | A |
| D | I | C | K | E | N | S | ■ | A | ■ | ■ | L |
| ■ | E | L | ■ | ■ | A | E | ■ | F | L | I | P |
| G | R | I | E | F | ■ | O | T | O | ■ | N | O |
| O | ■ | F | I | R | A | ■ | R | U | M | ■ | P |
| J | E | F | F | E | R | S | O | N | ■ | T | ■ |
| I | D | ■ | F | U | N | K | Y | T | O | W | N |
| ■ | ■ | M | E | D | I | A | ■ | A | R | A | E |
| B | A | E | L | ■ | C | ■ | G | I | N | I | R |
| A | G | A | T | H | A | ■ | ■ | N | A | N | O |
| B | ■ | D | O | E | ■ | S | T | E | M | ■ | ■ |
| B | R | O | W | N | ■ | A | R | ■ | E | V | E |
| ■ | O | W | E | N | ■ | M | A | N | N | E | R |
| E | N | ■ | R | Y | E | ■ | P | A | T | E | R |

with the letters appearing in the following numerical order:

> F U N K Y T O W A G E S R B V L M C D I P J H (with Q, X, Z not present).

Comment: You have one letter wrong. And I have updated the bottom rows of the text version as Sconibulus noticed I got them wrong while copying them. :)

Comment: @MariaDeleva Sorry, can you give me a hint about which letter? I can't find any hole in my logic so far (unless you've used some non-English words in the crossword). There doesn't seem to be any choice for 13 which will fit both `A 13 A E` and `13 A M A` (except L, which is already taken).

Comment: This is the letter, but perhaps you are missing a possibility. ;)

Comment: 13 might be R, for Arae (greek) Rama (Hindu) and err(English)

Comment: @MariaDeleva OK, I think I found it :-) (I did think it odd that there were so many G's ...)

Comment: @Sconibulus Thanks; I'd just realised that and edited before seeing your comment :-)

Answer (score 11):

Complete crossword:

> ```
>  A   G   N   E   S   A   R   B   E   R       V
>  R   A       L   E   E       E   R   A   T   O
>  T   U   R   I   N   G       L       M   A   C
>      T           S   I       L   L   A   M   A
>  D   I   C   K   E   N   S       A           L 
>      E   L           A   E       F   L   I   P
>  G   R   I   E   F       O   T   O       N   O
>  O       F   I   R   A       R   U   M       P
>  J   E   F   F   E   R   S   O   N       T
>
>  I   D       F   U   N   K   Y   T   O   W   N
>          M   E   D   I   A       A   R   A   E 
>  B   A   E   L       C       G   I   N   I   R 
>  A   G   A   T   H   A           N   A   N   O
>  B       D   O   E       S   T   E   M
>
>  B   R   O   W   N       A   R       E   V   E 
>      O   W   E   N       M   A   N   N   E   R 
>  E   N       R   Y   E       P   A   T   E   R
> ```

In the following, all ? have to be the same letter. 
Starting with the beginning of Rand's answer:

> First of all, I see the word `16 16 9 17 9` near the top right. Words starting with double letters are rare, and the only English word which fits this is LLAMA. That gives us:
>
> - `9 = A`
> - `16 = L`
> - `17 = M`
>
> Then in the upper middle we have a 3-letter word `16 11 11`, which must be either LEE or LOO. There are no 6-letter words beginning with AO and ending with A, so it must be LEE, giving:
>
> - `11 = E`
>
> Now we have `13 9 7 9` near the top right and `9 13 9 11` on the right-hand side, leading me to the conclusion that these are [RAMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rama) and [ARAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arae). So:
>
> - `13 = R`
>
> The word `A R 6` in the top left must be ART or ARC or ARK (since E and M are taken). The relative frequency of 6, as well as the words `12 6 E M` and `6 R A 21` in the lower right and `E R A 6 7` in the upper right, suggests that:
>
> - `6 = T`
>
> Then `E R A 6 7` must be [ERATO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erato) (and `7 6 7` in the middle is [OTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordo_Templi_Orientis)), giving:
>
> - `7 = O`
>
> And `12 T E M` in the lower right must be STEM, giving:
>
> - `12 = S`
>
> The combination of `S E 3 S E` at the top and `M A 3 3 E R` at the bottom right makes me quite sure that:
>
> - `3 = N`
>
> Now the combination of `23 E N N 5` at the bottom and `T R O 5` in the middle makes me quite sure that:
>
> - `5 = Y`

Continuing from there:

> MEA?O? looks like MEADOW, so 19=D and 8=W

From there,

> MED?A then has to be MEDIA, from where 20=I

This leaves an easy clue in the form of:

> This forms EI??ELTOWER, so 1=F to form EIFFELTOWER

Also:

> LAFO?NTAINE looks like a misspelling of La Fontaine as La Fountaine, so 2=U (this also fits with the crossing R?M, which makes RUM).

Then:

> ARNI?A is easy to fill as ARNICA, so 18=C

From there:

> ?ROWN crosses ?A??, the most likely letter for 14 is then B (BABB is a surname, and no other letter would fit both).

Continuing:

> A?NESARBER can only be Agnes Arber, so 10=G. This also forms TURING and GAUTIER.

Another word:

> From DIC?ENS, we have 4=K. This forms FUNK?TOWN in the middle, so 5=Y. This solves the cryptic clue:
>
>  Amusing key glues crazy = FUNKY (FUN+KY ~ crazy)

Filling in the last letters:

> AGAT?A crosses ?ENNY, so 23=H and we get AGATHA and HENNY.
>  ?EFFERSON looks like it could be nothing but a J, so 22=J.

Delivering the final blow, in the top-right corner we have a word with two different unused letters:

> 15 OCAL 21 O 21.
>  By elimination of the already used letters, I concluded that this should be VOCALPOP (also forming EVE, TRAP and PATER in the bottom-right corner).